# how to remove a record in an array or object by knowing the value of the record to be removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Array as following

```
[
    { id: "172~~81259", title: "Absurdity (Theatre)" },
    { id: "2803~~281318", title: "Academic Administration" },
    { id: "3722~~296974", title: "Accessories Design" },
    { id: "23843", title: "Accommodation and Front Office Professional" },
    { id: "16834", title: "Accountant" },
    { id: "853~~64400", title: "Accounting Information System" },
    { id: "4403~~40149", title: "Activation and Experiential Advertising" },
    { id: "15~~39301", title: "Activation and Experiential Advertising" }
]
```

I want to filter(remove) already selected values from this array.so how can i filter by knowing the value only.

Comment: Can you let us know that value?

Comment: More context required. Can you please add it?

Comment: You say you want to remove already selected items, but how can you determine what is/is not selected?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan By _the value_. Jokes aside, I'm assuming they have another array with either the id or the title and want to filter it out using that.

Comment: use `array.filter(thevalueyoudontwanttotellus);`

Comment: If the first selected title value is 'Academic Administration' then we need to remove that total record and need to display remaining records for the user as dropdown.

Comment: Thanks all for replies. @tipsfedora yeah got idea, now problem solved thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). It generates a new array containing only the items which cause the supplied callback to return `true`. Use that callback to check the value you want to check, whatever that value is.